# Allow authenticated users to create taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

Currently I categorize content using nodes as categories, because authenticated users cannot create taxonomy terms.

What would be the way(s) to accomplish a term/add page for authenticated users?

Answer (score 1):

[Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) provides finer control of taxonomy permissions, that sounds like what you need.

Comment: hm I wanted to prevent another access control module, but it probably the easiest way. Thanks